# How do I create a strongly typed BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've seen a few examples of people using this syntax for HTML.BeginForm:

```
(Html.BeginForm<Type>(action => action.ActionName(id)))
```

But when I try this syntax all I get is a:

```
The non-generic method System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)'
cannot be used with type arguments
```

What am I missing?
Visual Studio 2010, System.Web.MVC version is v2.0.50727

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will find this extension methods in [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) and more specifically in the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll` assembly in the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FormExtensions` class. So download and include this assembly in your project and add the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` namespace in the `namespaces` section of your web.config file:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
    <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
</namespaces>
```

and you will be able to use it in your views.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is along the right tracks.  However, I add the reference and add the namespace and still get this error.  Is it just MVCContrib I need or also MVCFutures?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example, in your .aspx view:

"`UserController`" being your controller.
"`Save()`" being your action method in the controller.

```
<%
using (Html.BeginForm<UserController>(x => x.Save(null, null, Model.User.ID, null, null), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formUser" })) {
%>
   <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
   <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
   ...
<% } %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's complaining because BeginForm doesn't have that signature.  "cannot be used with type arguments"